# button float drops below parent div

Tags: html, css

Given this simplified snippet :

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div>
      <div style='text-align:center;'>asdfaskjdfakjsd</div>
      <div style='float:right'>
        <input type='submit' value='asdf' />
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

The button floats to the right, but below the text(On the next line). I know I can realign it using relative positioning, but is there a correct way of having both on the same line.

Even better if adding the button on the right would not effect the centre align of the text. ie it does not get pushed to the left.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I apologize for jumping around. I noticed that even with the reversed divs, the text didn't appear completely centered.

Here is yet another solution (5th example): http://jsfiddle.net/tracyfu/zYzqr/

```
#method5 {
  position: relative;
}

#method5 .submit {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
}
```

The only problem with this is that if you're not careful, or your text is dynamic, it could collide with the absolutely positioned submit.

Comment: Thanks for that. If you look at this one : http://jsfiddle.net/zYzqr/1/ the last one without the button, is there a way to get the text to align the same way with the button.

Comment: Yes. I updated my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tracyfu/zYzqr/) to center all the text, but I think @StevenH pretty much has the best solution for you.

Answer (score 4):

You can switch the order of the two divs:

```
  <div style='float:right'>
    <input type='submit' value='asdf' />
  </div>
  <div>asdfaskjdfakjsd</div>
```

As long as you don't mind them being in reverse order.

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tracyfu/zYzqr/) to demonstrate this effect. The fourth example shows the divs reversed.

Comment: This solution is the easiest. I like to have my HTML in a specific order, but I've definitely resorted to this method on a number of occasions.

Comment: Why does that work ? Also if the text is center aligned it gets pushed to the left to make room for the button. Is there a way to keep the text in the center disregarding the button.

Comment: This works because floats (all els) are laid out in the order specified by the HTML. If your content div comes first, the DOM will put the div on the page and your floated content will be laid out and floated after the div. If you put the float down first, it will be placed, then floated. Because a float doesn't 'take up space' because it's been pulled out of the flow of content, content that comes after it appears to be inline with the float. -_- Sorry for such a convoluted explanation.

Comment: The way a browser flows the elements around a `float`ed element is: An element is floated, then all elements **following** the floated element are positioned according to the style rules applied to them. Which means that elements *before* the floated element are **not** repositioned, and the element floated retains it's vertical position. (Or what Tracy said. Beat me to the punch!)

Comment: @StevenH I'm going to remove my solution in favor of this one. Here's my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tracyfu/zYzqr/) that demonstrates 4 solutions with centered text.

Comment: @TracyFu excellent demo. Kassim, AFAIK the only way to prevent the floated div's width from being included in the centering calculation is to use relative positioning, as you mention in your question. Example here: http://jsfiddle.net/hmkG7/ If anyone knows an alternative, I would be happy to be proven wrong!

Answer (score 1):

I misunderstood your question the first time. You should add `float:left;` on your initial div and also make sure to add `clear:both;` to the div below them. If you want the text to be centered, you need to have a width on the initial div.

**HTML**:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="content">
        asdfaskjdfakjsd
    </div>
    <div id="containerButton">
        <input type='submit' value='asdf' />
    </div>   
</div>
<div class="clear">asdfaskjdfakjsd</div>
```

CSS:

```
#container {
    width:300px;   
}

#content {    
    float:left;
    text-align:center; 
    width:90%;
}

#containerButton {
    text-align:right;
​}

.clear {
    clear:both;
​}​
```

[Live DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/pP285/9/)

Comment: Does not seem to work. It just makes the parent div include both objects. ie parent div spans two lines now.

Comment: I added a demo. Does the demo not do what you want?

Comment: That works as long as the text is aligned on the left. What if the text needs to be in the center?

Comment: You need to set a width in the text div in order for that to work.

Answer (score 1):

The standard approach is to use the "clearfix" hack. CSS:

```
/* For modern browsers */
.cf:before,
.cf:after {
    content:"";
    display:table;
}

.cf:after {
    clear:both;
}

/* For IE 6/7 (trigger hasLayout) */
.cf {
    *zoom:1;
}
```

Credit [Nicolas Gallagher](http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/). Then wrap your line in a `cf` element:

```
<div class="cf">
    <span>Button text</span>
    <div style='float:right'>
        <input type='submit' value='asdf' />
    </div>
</div>
```

Button text is changed to a `span`, or you could leave it as a `div` and float it left. `cf` is used to give block properties to a set of elements that do not naturally exhibit them. Without it, ensuing content will not be cleared.

- [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/paislee/SZbhy/)

Comment: I encourage you to take a look at Nicolas Gallagher's clearfix solution http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/ I really like this method. It's much slimmer. I would also encourage directly applying clearfixes to element style declarations and to avoid classes that describe markup.

Comment: @TracyFu I included the leaner clearfix solution. Wouldn't applying clearfix styles to every element that needed it result in bloated CSS files? Also could you explain what you mean by "avoid classes that describe markup"? Thx

Comment: Yes sorry for not clarifying. I've been using [Sass](http://sass-lang.com/) for awhile that makes this possible. I think the `clearfix` class is okay; my style has been to avoid classes like `left` that describe a specific visual behavior. 'Best practices' as described by some folks are to use semantic classes that describe content over those that describe behavior. That said, I read [this](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2012/06/19/classes-where-were-going-we-dont-need-classes/) the other day which screwed up my thinking on semantic HTML. In conclusion, perhaps don't listen to me :)